# How to do group by values in list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

`[{'A': '1', 'P': '3253'},{'A': '2', 'P': '3127'},{'A': '1', 'P': '3056'}]`

Print the Unique number of A value
For each **unique** A value, what is the **average** P (grouped by A value)
output should be:

`[('A':'1', 'P':'3154.5'},{'A': '2', 'P': '3127'}]`

Comment: what have you tried so far? could you please add your code?

Answer (score 0):

First gather all the like keys to calculate the average:

```
LoD=[{'A': '1', 'P': '3253'},{'A': '2', 'P': '3127'},{'A': '1', 'P': '3056'}]

out={}
for d in LoD:
    k=('A', d['A'])
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(float(d['P']))
```

Then reformat into a list of dicts with the average:

```
newLoD=[{t[0]:t[1], 'P':str(sum(sl)/len(sl))} for t,sl in out.items()]  

>>> newLoD
[{'A': '1', 'P': '3154.5'}, {'A': '2', 'P': '3127.0'}]
```